# Firebase not get the token id for web app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-notifications

As per this video instruction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsCBCudx58g, I have integrated the code it looks below.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.5/firebase.js"></script>
<script>

  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "IIzaSyA3MZtKiK6E6y7q9w26J-YMi9Leeao5Zs0",
    authDomain: "a...99.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://a...99.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "a...99.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "915965251026"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function() {
    alert('Notification permission granted.');

    return messaging.getToken();

    }).then(function(token){
        alert(token);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        alert('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    });

</script>
```

**manifest.json file**

```
{
  "short_name": "AirHorner",
  "name": "Kinlan's AirHorner of Infamy",

  "start_url": "index.html?launcher=true"
}
```

Also I have created a dummy "firebase-messaging-sw.js" file

**What error I faced**

When I execute it, **Notification permission granted** alert was executed, and suddenly display **Unable to get permission to notify** message and in the **err** argument I got the following error

> browserErrorMessage
>   :
>   "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script."
>   code
>   :
>   "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
>   message
>   :
>   "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."
>   stack
>   :
>   "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.5/firebase.js:552:225"

In **message.getToken()** return the following value

> _proto__
>   :
>   Promise
>   [[PromiseStatus]]
>   :
>   "pending"
>   [[PromiseValue]]
>   :
>   undefined

Comment: It lookks like it can't find the service worker script. Do you have a `firebase-messaging-sw.js`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you very much, I created but it is not in home directory. So it is not worked. Now my problem is solved.

Comment: Good to hear. It'd be good to post a self-answer explaining that your had to put `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in the root directory.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you know how to send push notification from http://onlinecurl.com/ here I tried but it show "HTTP/1.1 401 The request was missing an Authentification Key (FCM Token)" error

Comment: Get SSL and run in secure transfer protocol

Comment: I am using apache, where should I keep firebase-messaging-sw.js. I have tried to store it in my project directory and also in webapps folder but it's not working

Comment: For Eg: in Apache tomcat do we have to set the js file in root ? or In project directory root ?